# Does returning values from an event handler makes the Subgraph to crash?

Tags: subgraph, assemblyscript, thegraph

I tried returning the entity objects from the event handlers on the AssemblyScript Subgraph code to simplify unit testing. For example, this works fine:

```js
// Original code
export function handleEventCreation(
       event: EventCreation
): void {
...
}
```

but this fails:

```js
// Failing code in Subgraph (it compiles well)
export function handleEventCreation(
     event: EventCreation,
): CreationEntity | null {
...
}
```

Both examples compile well.

Is there any explanation for that?
In the Subgraph API site, I see that it failed indexing events only, but no further details about it.

Comment: Can you show the stack traces from the error on the second example?

Comment: I didn't find a way to get the stack traces once the code is deployed to Subgraph and fails. I could only see the error message: "failed indexing events". There are no enough details unfortunately.